# Unable to switch to Dvorak layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I need to switch my keyboard to Dvorak layout. I've done this a number of times through the GUI and never had problems until now.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS codename trusty, Xfce4 & xfce4-xkb-plugin. The plugin only shows one layout. When I got to Keyboard Settings -> Layouts, the keyboard model drop down is empty and so are the "change layout option" and "compose key" dropdowns. I'm not able to add or delete keyboard layouts.

I tried switching on the command line by doing the following:

1. Create `.Xkbmap` file in my home directory with the following content:

   ```
   -layout us -variant dvorak -option compose:102 -option numpad:shift3 -option kpdl:semi -option keypad:atm -option caps:shift
   ```
2. Modified `/etc/default/console-setup` on include the following:

   ```
   XKBLAYOUT="us"
   XKBVARIANT="dvorak"
   XKBOPTIONS="compose:102, numpad:shift3, kpdl:semi, keypad:atm, caps:shift"
   ```
3. Tried reconfiguring the keyboard by running:

   ```
   dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
   ```

I also uninstalled ibus, which I read can cause problems on Ubuntu 14.04.
I tried switching the input method as well.

None of it has worked. This is on a remote VM that I access over remote desktop connection from my Windows machine.

Comment: What does `setxkbmap dvorak` say? BTW, I also use Dvorak.

Comment: XKB extension not present on :10.0. xkb-data, xkbing & xkbset are all installed.

Comment: Did you update `X server` on this machine?

Comment: No, but I ran sudo apt-get update and it's all up to date.

Comment: `apt-get update` only updates a local repository of available packages, it does not upgrade system. Lack of `xkb` may be the reason why you cannot switch to dvorak layout.

Comment: Not following. What package do I need to install? x11-xkb-utils is already installed.

Comment: I don't know what you should do, I don't use `Ubuntu` that much. But if `setxkbmap` doesn't work because of missing `XKB` extension I would look more into `XKB`.

Comment: Start from searching at google: https://www.google.pl/search?q=%22XKB+extension+not+present+on%22&btnG=Search&hl=en&gws_rd=cr

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an X Window System, then `setxkbmap dvorak` is the command you're looking for.
If you're on a terminal without X, then give `loadkeys dvorak` a try!